# How do I change the Gitweb default diff format to `--color-words`?

Tags: perl, git, diff, gitweb

I want gitweb to output the same diff format as `git diff --color-words`.  Does anybody know how I can do this?  I looked at HTML::FromANSI but couldn't get it working with `git diff --color-words` from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you use [HTML::FromANSI](http://p3rl.org/HTML::FromANSI)? Because it works for me, using the following command worked as intended

```
git diff --color-words HEAD^ HEAD |
perl -wle '
use HTML::FromANSI; 
my @lines = <STDIN>; 
foreach my $line (@lines) {
    chomp $line;
    print ansi2html($line); 
}' > tmp.html
```

Although if you want usable output, and not barely visible white text on black background, you would probably need to configure HTML::FromANSI.  The above scriptlet is just proof of concept code (ans not in best style).

---

BTW I am not sure about quality of [HTML::FromANSI](http://p3rl.org/HTML::FromANSI) module; it didn't install (using `cpan`) for me without force (but it might be problem with Term::VT102::Boundless this module requires).

`ansi2html` subroutine have problems with some lines (I think lines with embedded / trailing end-of-line character, and empty line / string), producing `Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at .../HTML/FromANSI.pm line 353, <STDIN> line NN.` warning.  That's why I had to `chomp` lines *(and that might be the problem you had with making HTML::FromANSI work)*.

Also the HTML produced by this module is quite horrid, using outdated and deprecated `<font face='...' style ='...'>` tag together with modern `<span style='...'>` tag; also I don't see an option to use CSS instead of inline style.

Comment: Yeah, looking at the source, it would require some hacking to get working nicely.